# Should new/new[] match delete/delete[]?

Tags: c++

I knew that when we allocate memory by using new/new[], then we should release the memory by using the delete/delete[] respectively.

Here is the question,

Can I use delete[] to release the memory allocated by new?

For example,

```
int *pInt3 = new int;
delete [] pInt3;
pInt3 = NULL;

T *pT3 = new T;
delete [] pT3;
pT3 = NULL;
```

Thank you

Comment: Why are you asking the question when you already know the answer?

Comment: would not make any sense to have delete[] and delete if that was possible.

Comment: @wnoise, The reason why I am asking is that new int or new T is to create an array of size one. So it seems that it should work if the delete[] is used. -- thx

Comment: q0987: Why waste time wondering whether it might work in some particular case? Just use the matching form of `delete` and get on with your work. Surely there are more interesting aspects of programming to discuss than the recurring SO questions about `new/delete/new[]/delete[]` and `i++ = ++i + i++`.

Comment: q0987: No, there is a difference between a single object of type T, and an array of type T of size 1.  The actual memory allocation for the data may be the same (one item of type T), but the bookkeeping around the data allocated is unlikely to be the same at all.  In particular, for an array of length 1, that length of 1 needs to be stored somewhere, but it doesn't for a single element.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you should match the non-array form of `new` with non-array `delete`, and likewise for the array forms.

See the [C++ FAQ Lite section on Freestore Management](http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html)

This is especially good: http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.12

> [16.12] What if I forget the [] when deleteing array allocated via new T[n]?
>
> All life comes to a catastrophic end.
>
> It is the programmer's —not the compiler's— responsibility to get the connection between new T[n] and delete[] p correct. If you get it wrong, neither a compile-time nor a run-time error message will be generated by the compiler. Heap corruption is a likely result. Or worse. Your program will probably die.

Comment: In fact, my concern is not 16.12. My question is what if I always use [] when delete an allocated object. -- thank you

Comment: @q0987 - how `new []` is implemented may differ from how scalar `new` is implemented, and according to C++03 standard, calling `delete[]` on a pointer not allocated with a corresponding `new[]` call is undefined.

Answer (score 5):

I guess that you are not satisfied with anything but a reference to the standard, so here it is.

You can find it under 3.7.3.2 in the Standard for C++03.

> 3 The value of the first argument supplied to one of the deallocation functions provided in the standard library may be a null pointer value; if so, the call to the deallocation function has no effect. Otherwise, the value supplied to operator delete(void*) in the standard library shall be one of the values returned by a previous invocation of either operator new(size_t) or operator new(size_t, const std::nothrow_t&) in the standard library, and **the value supplied to operator delete[] (void*) in the standard library shall be one of the values returned by a previous invocation of either operator new[] (size_t) or operator new[] (size_t, const std::nothrow_t&) in the standard library**.

So the answer to your question is no.

Comment: may you give me a link so that I can refer to the C++ standard for above description?

Comment: @q0897 - you have to get a copy of the standard, which is $30.

Comment: I bought mine at http://webstore.ansi.org/. You can get a draft (for free) of the next standard here: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/SC22-N-4411.pdf. In that document you can find it under item 3 under 3.7.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use delete[] to release the
>   memory allocated by new?

Yes you *could*, but you will be sorry if you do.