# The difference between delete and delete[] in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, delete-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [delete vs delete[] operators in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425728/delete-vs-delete-operators-in-c)

I've written a class that contains two pointers, one is `char* color_` and one in `vertexesset* vertex_` where `vertexesset` is a class I created. In the destractor I've written at start

```
delete [] color_;
delete [] vertex_;
```

When It came to the destructor it gave me a segmentation fault.

Then I changed the destructor to:

```
delete [] color_;
delete vertex_;
```

And now it works fine. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: can you post the code where you allocated the two pointers? i.e. the new part.

Comment: Did you follow the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553382/pod-freeing-memory-is-delete-equal-to-delete

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You `delete []` when you `new`ed an array type, and `delete` when you didn't. Examples:

```
typedef int int_array[10];

int* a = new int;
int* b = new int[10];
int* c = new int_array;

delete a;
delete[] b;
delete[] c; // this is a must! even if the new-line didn't use [].
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the case with int_array.

Comment: Copying from the comment to the other answer: It is a bad idea to use array typedefs, but it's not a bad idea to mention it, people get bitten by it. Also, the point is that even when you _wrote_ `new`, you sometimes need to _write_ `delete[]`.

Comment: Someone edited the typedef - the way it is now (and has been originally) is the correct one, please try your "fixes" before you edit. See http://ideone.com/fYh6MK vs http://ideone.com/w9fPKr

Comment: I'm interested to know what you would require if you had the following: char** strings = new char*[2]; strings[0]=new char[10]; strings[1] = new char[10]; Would delete [] strings clear all the memory or just the string array, leaving me to clear the two char arrays?

Comment: @Mahen it would just delete the pointers to the strings, delete the array contents beforehand.

Answer (score 25):

`delete` and `delete[]` are not the same thing! Wikipedia [explains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_(C%2B%2B)) this, if briefly. In short, `delete []` invokes the destructor **on every element** in the allocated array, while `delete` assumes you have exactly one instance. You should allocate arrays with `new foo[]` and delete them with `delete[]`; for ordinary objects, use `new` and `delete`. Using `delete[]` on a non-array could lead to havoc.

Comment: This should be the answer, it actually explains the difference. Thanks.

Comment: yea this lost 40 upvotes because it was 2 minutes later. important to note you can't use delete[] as a catch-all solution to handle raw pointers.

Comment: Why doesn't the C++ runtime just figure out the difference between array and non-array types so that programmers can just use a single `delete` statement?

Comment: It would have to be the compiler, not the runtime. The runtime only sees calls to `malloc` and `free` (for example).

Answer (score 9):

- If you allocate with malloc(), you use free()
- If you allocate with new you use delete
- If you allocate with new[] you use delete[]
- If you construct with placement-new you call the destructor direct
- If it makes sense to use vector rather than new[] then use it
- If it makes sense to use smart-pointers then use them and don't bother to call delete (but you'll still need to call new). The matching delete will be in the smart-pointer.

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt

Comment: `If you allocate with new you use delete` - this is not always the case, see my answer.

Comment: @etarion:  I see nothing in your answer that contradicts this statement; your use of a type alias sill invokes `new[]` not `new`, the type alias simply obfuscates that fact and is probably a bad idea (even to mention it!).

Comment: It is a bad idea to use array typedefs, but it's not a bad idea to mention it, people get bitten by it. Also, the point is that even when you _wrote_ `new`, you sometimes need to _write_ `delete[]`.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `delete []` if you allocated memory on the heap with operator `new[]` (e.g. a dynamic array).

If you used operator `new`, you must use operator `delete`, without the square brackets.

It is not related to deleting a built-in type or a custom class.

Comment: It does not hurt, however, to use delete[] on anything created with new. The segfault must have another reason.

Comment: Where do you get the idea that it doesn't hurt? It's wrong.

Comment: @ypnos: In what universe does undefined behavior *not* hurt? :)

Comment: Undefined behavior always hurts, just not always right away.

Answer (score 2):

When we want to free a memory allocated to a pointer to an object then "delete" is used.

```
int * p;
p=new int;

// now to free the memory 
delete p;
```

But when we have allocated memory for array of objects like

```
int * p= new int[10]; //pointer to an array of 10 integer
```

then to free memory equal to 10 integers:

```
 delete []p;
```

NOTE: One can free the memory even by `delete p;`, but it will free only the first element memory.

Comment: `new int(10)` allocates a single `int`, not an array of 10 `int`.

Comment: ***NOTE: One can free the memory even by delete p;, but it will free only the first element memory.*** This note is wrong. The following question explains why: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480722/should-new-new-match-delete-delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480722/should-new-new-match-delete-delete)

Answer (score 1):

If you have [Effective C++ part 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201924889) refer to Item #5: Use the same form in corresponding uses of new and delete.

Comment: And if you don't have Effective C++, buy it now!

Answer (score 1):

Raymond Chen provides a detailed description of how scaler and vector delete works in his blog titled [Mismatching scalar and vector new and delete](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/03/66660.aspx).

Here's a link to the InformIT article that is mis-linked in the above article: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30642

Answer (score 0):

> And now it works fine.

More by luck that judgement if it does, and are you certain that it is really working?

The destructor for every object must be called, the `delete[]` operator uses information set by `new[]` to determine how many objects to destroy.  So while `delete` on its own may recover the memory (though whether it does or not is implementation dependent), it may not call the destructor for each object allocated.

It is possible for the information about how the object's were allocated to be included when `new` or `new[]` are called so that the correct form of deletion is used regardless, but again that is implementation dependent and not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, consider **not using** pointers if you don't **really** have to. e.g. `char*` can be replaced with `std::string`, and if your `vertexesset` member is not polymorphic, you can make it a member object. In this case, you wouldn't need `delete` at all