# Is this the right way to write a destructor?

Tags: c++, destructor

Besides a lot of member functions, my Graph class has 3 main members: a vector of pointers to its vertices, called "vertex", a vector of pointers to its edges, called "edge", and an integer counter variable. I started/attempted to write the destructor to deallocate the memory from the vectors, but I'm not sure if I am doing it correctly. And what do I do about the counter? I tried to say "delete counter," but it's not a pointer (oops).

```
Graph<Object,Weight>::~Graph(){
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<vertex.size(); ++i){
                delete vertex[i]; }
        for(unsigned int j=0; j<edge.size(); ++j){
                delete edge[j]; }

        //counter? 
}
```

Comment: Could you have `vector<Vertex>` instead of `vector<Vertex*>`, etc? Then they would clean-up themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is `counter` a plain ordinary **int** variable?    If so, you're not in charge of its lifetime.

The **delete** keyword is only to be used when you've created an object with the **new** keyword.   (And even then, only when there isn't something else in your program, such as shared_ptr which is doing the delete for you)

When using new/delete you're taking over from the language and managing the lifetime/existance of an object yourself.   ordinary variables are created and destroyed automatically, meaning you don't need to worry about them.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting depends on the way you allocated, see [The difference between delete and delete [] in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670782/the-difference-between-delete-and-delete-in-c)

As for your int member, since you didn't dynamically allocate it (you didn't use new) you don't have to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the type of `vertex` is `std::vector<Vertex*>` and you create the vector as follows:

```
vertex.push_back( new Vertex );
```

your clean up code looks correct.

**But, I urge you not to do this.** Declare `vertex` as `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Vertex>>` and you don't need to worry about `delete`ing the individual vector members anymore.

If you're using Boost, you could also make `vertex` a [`boost::ptr_vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html).

As for the `counter` variable, unless you're `new`ing the counter somewhere during class construction, you don't need to `delete` it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `vertex` and `edge` are allocated using `new`? then what you have written is fine but if you declared your `vertex` and `edge` as an array and `new`ed using `new []` operator then you need to use the `delete []` call instead of `delete`, if the counter was not declared as a pointer and `new`ed then there is no need to delete the counter.

As a design decision you should consider declaring your `vertex` and `edge` objects as `boost::shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` so that they are reference counted and when the `Graph` object goes out of scope they are automatically cleaned up so you don't even need to flesh out your destructor.

If you have c++11 then you can use the `std` versions and not need `boost` like `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: You dont need boost for that anymore, `std::unique_ptr​` and `std::shared_ptr` are there in **C++11** :)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete an array of pointers with:

```
del[] arr; // arr is array of pointers.
```

Whereas, if `counter` is from stack, the program will take care of it, and you as programmer don't need to worry about freeing that memory.

Comment: hmm... i think this code will crash my application if called:

void foo()
{
 void* array_of_pointers[12] = {};
 delete[] array_of_pointers;
}