# C++ memory leakage: new a pointer in function and delete outside

Tags: c++, function, memory-leaks

My code is as this:

```
// a function that new a char pointer and return it
Unsigned char* RGB2GS(Unsigned char* pRgb, int nw, int nh, int nbpp) {
    unsigned char* pGs = new unsigned char[nw*nh*nbpp];

    // code for rgb to gs...//
    return pGs;
}

int main() {
    unsigned char* pmyRgb = ReadBmp(filename);//size 1024x1024, RGB
    unsigned char* pMyGs = NULL;
    pMyGs = RGB2GS(pmyRgb, 1024, 1024, 24);
    delete[] pMyGs ;
    delete[] pmyRgb ; // correct typo
```

I found there is memory leakage(from VS2010 log). I created a pointer inside a function and return it. But I deleted the pointer outside the function. Is that a problem in this usage? thanks

Comment: Why are you deleting twice?

Comment: Also, writing code like this is just asking for leaks. Use RAII!

Comment: why this code is asking for leaks? I tried to implement the function rgb2gs. I think it is more logical to created the GS char pointer inside it and return. But please tell me what is a better way to do so? thank a lot.

Comment: This is asking for leaks since if the `new` in `RGB2GS` throws, `pmyRgb` would never get deleted. Use `std::vector<unsigned char>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The leaked memory is probably the BMP data, `pmyRgb`. Check the docs for that function. You have deleted the memory at `pMyGs` just fine. Doing it twice isn't usually harmful but it is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a memory multiple times will have undefied behavior. There is nothing wrong in allocating a memory in a function, returning it, and deleting another place. Point to note is there is a difference between `delete[]` and `delete`, but since you are allocating memory as an array, `delete[]` is safe to use.

[The difference between delete and delete [] in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670782/the-difference-between-delete-and-delete-in-c)[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670782/the-difference-between-delete-and-delete-in-c)

Comment: sorry, i made a typo. should be:
delete[] pMyGs ;
delete[] pmyRgb ;
so I guess my code should not have memory leakage, right?

Comment: looking at the code that you have pasted, I dnt see any leaks :)