# Is it safe to use delete instead of delete[] on a POD array?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, delete-operator

I'm writing some memory management code in C++, and at first I use `char *ptr = new char[1024]` instead of `void *malloc(unsigned int size)` to get a buffer, after this, there's no concept of array in my code, all the operation is done by pointers.

But when I want to free them, I got some worries. As far as I know, C++ asked programmers to use `delete[]` when acquire memory by using `new *type*[]`, but at this moment I only got a pointer (which is `ptr` in the case above). Before coding this I think why using `delete[]` is to call the destructors on each element. But I'm not sure if there's a difference between `delete` and `delete[]` on a pod array.

So is it safe to use `delete ptr` on a pod array?

Comment: Matching `new[]` with plain `delete` leads to *undefined behavior*, end of story. Just don't do such things.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Concise, thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry for maybe sounding a little rude, but there's really not much more to say :)

Comment: It is not safe. Possible duplicate of [delete vs delete\[\] operators in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2425728/608639), [The difference between delete and delete\[\] in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4670782/608639), etc. For a concrete example of the problem, see Raymond Chen's [Mismatching scalar and vector new and delete](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=40763).

Answer (score 3):

`new` comes with `delete`. `new []` comes with `delete []`. You have no other [option](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete):

> Called by delete-expressions to deallocate storage previously
>   allocated for a single object. The behavior of the standard library
>   implementation of this function is undefined unless ptr is a null
>   pointer or is a pointer previously obtained from the standard library
>   implementation of operator new(size_t) or operator new(size_t,
>   std::nothrow_t).

Mixing these operators results in undefined behavior.