# Delete without square brackets on dynamic array

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

Consider:

```
int *p = new int[10];
```

The [linked reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4670844/2725810) states:

> NOTE: One can free the memory even by delete p;, but it will free only the first element memory.

This sounds like `delete p` is OK. Is this correct? I would expect that `delete p` should result in undefined behavior...

Comment: A memory leak is not undefined behavior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should new/new\[\] match delete/delete\[\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480722/should-new-new-match-delete-delete)

Comment: The dynamic array is allocated as one block of contiguous memory.  Deleting one cell in the block is undefined behavior and a pain to maintain the memory allocation (i.e. how does one mark a memory cell of an array as deleted but keep all the others?).

Comment: C++11 Paragraph 5.3/2 : "[...] In the first alternative (delete object), the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer value, a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous new-expression, or a pointer to a subobject ([intro.object]) representing a base class of such an object (Clause [class.derived]). If not, the behavior is undefined. [...]"

Comment: It is UB using version of `delete` that doesn't match `new`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not OK, and the statement is not correct.

The behaviour of using `delete` on a pointer from `new[]` (or indeed, any pointer not from `new`) is undefined. `delete[]` should be used instead.